# Highlighting elements in matrices and linking them with other parameters with arrows

Tags: matrices, highlighting

I would like to highlight some elements in a matrix and link them with arrows to their definition given on the matrix side (like in the picture below).
I know there are possibilities to highlight elements in a matrix with TikZ, but is it possible to have boxes, arrows, and text (math symbols) on the side? What is the easiest way to do this? Is it possible to do this without TikZ?[image]

Here is my code so far:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs}

\begin{document}
\begin{eqnarray}
    \mathbf{N} &=& \begin{pmatrix}
        n_{11} & 0 & n_{13} & n_{14} \\
        n_{21} & n_{22} & n_{23} & n_{24} \\
        n_{31} & n_{32} & n_{33} & 0 \\
        n_{41} & n_{42} & n_{43} & n_{44} 
    \end{pmatrix}\\
     &=& \begin{pmatrix}
        \sqrt{\beta_x} & 0 & n_{13} & n_{14} \\
        -\frac{\alpha_x}{\sqrt{\beta_x}} & n_{22} & n_{23} & n_{24} \\
        n_{31} & n_{32} & \sqrt{\beta_y} & 0 \\
        n_{41} & n_{42} & -\frac{\alpha_y}{\sqrt{\beta_y}} & n_{44} 
    \end{pmatrix}
\end{eqnarray}

\end{document}
```

Thank you already for your help!

Comment: The easiest way to overlap arrows and text is to put `\tikzmark`s into the matrix and overlay a tikzpicture.  There are many example here.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301). I'd second @JohnKormylo's suggestion to use `\tikzmark` (depending on how the matrices are written). FYI, It is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) that sets up the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it. In this case the MWE could produce the two matrcies -- the solution's depend on exactly how you are creating the matrices.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. I edited my question to add the MWE with the two matrices! I will try to learn more about \tikzmark, but I have never used TikZ before,  so any advice is welcome! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is with TikZ, forgive me.

The problem is that what you want to draw is too large for only one column of a two-column document.

Here are two possible solutions: in one column, with different positions of the description, or in two columns.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{mwe}% <--- for testing purpose only
\usepackage{cuted}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, fit}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{mymatrixstyle/.style={matrix of math nodes,
        ampersand replacement=\&,
        left delimiter=(,
        right delimiter=), 
        inner sep=0pt,
        outer sep=0pt,
        row sep=2pt, column sep=10pt},
        myarrow/.style={-{Straight Barb[angle=60:3pt 3]}}}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs}

\begin{document} 
\blindtext % <--- for testing purpose only

In one column:
%\begin{eqnarray} see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/197/101651
\begin{align}
    \mathbf{N} &= \begin{pmatrix}
        n_{11} & 0 & n_{13} & n_{14} \\
        n_{21} & n_{22} & n_{23} & n_{24} \\
        n_{31} & n_{32} & n_{33} & 0 \\
        n_{41} & n_{42} & n_{43} & n_{44} 
    \end{pmatrix}\\
     &= \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
        \matrix[mymatrixstyle] (mymatr) {
        \sqrt{\beta_x} \& 0 \& n_{13} \& n_{14} \&[-7pt]\\
        -\dfrac{\alpha_x}{\sqrt{\beta_x}} \& n_{22} \& n_{23} \& n_{24} \\
        n_{31} \& n_{32} \& \sqrt{\beta_y} \& 0 \\
        n_{41} \& n_{42} \& -\dfrac{\alpha_y}{\sqrt{\beta_y}} \& n_{44}\\};
        \node[draw, fit=(mymatr-3-1)(mymatr-3-2)] (n3132) {};
        \node[draw, fit=(mymatr-4-1)(mymatr-4-2)] (n4142) {};
        \node[draw, fit=(mymatr-1-3)(mymatr-1-4)] (n1314) {};
        \node[draw, fit=(mymatr-2-3)(mymatr-2-4)] (n2324) {};
        \draw[myarrow, overlay] (n3132) -- ++(-1.8,0) -| +(0,-1.6) node[anchor=north] {$\zeta_y=n_{31}+in_{32}$};
        \draw[myarrow] (n4142) -- +(0,-1.8) node[anchor=north] {$\tilde{\zeta}_y=n_{41}-in_{42}$};
        \draw[myarrow, overlay] (n1314) -- ++(2,0) -|  +(0,-3.6) node[anchor=20] {$\zeta_y=n_{13}-in_{14}$};
        \draw[myarrow, overlay] (n2324) -- ++(1.4,0) -|  +(0,-2.1) node[anchor=20] {$\tilde{\zeta}_y=n_{23}-in_{24}$};
    \end{tikzpicture}        
\end{align}

\blindtext[7] % <--- for testing purpose only

In two columns:

\begin{strip}
\begin{align}
    \mathbf{N} &= \begin{pmatrix}
        n_{11} & 0 & n_{13} & n_{14} \\
        n_{21} & n_{22} & n_{23} & n_{24} \\
        n_{31} & n_{32} & n_{33} & 0 \\
        n_{41} & n_{42} & n_{43} & n_{44} 
    \end{pmatrix}\\
     &= \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
        \matrix[mymatrixstyle] (mymatr) {
        \sqrt{\beta_x} \& 0 \& n_{13} \& n_{14} \&[-7pt]\\
        -\dfrac{\alpha_x}{\sqrt{\beta_x}} \& n_{22} \& n_{23} \& n_{24} \\
        n_{31} \& n_{32} \& \sqrt{\beta_y} \& 0 \\
        n_{41} \& n_{42} \& -\dfrac{\alpha_y}{\sqrt{\beta_y}} \& n_{44}\\};
        \node[draw, fit=(mymatr-3-1)(mymatr-3-2)] (n3132) {};
        \node[draw, fit=(mymatr-4-1)(mymatr-4-2)] (n4142) {};
        \node[draw, fit=(mymatr-1-3)(mymatr-1-4)] (n1314) {};
        \node[draw, fit=(mymatr-2-3)(mymatr-2-4)] (n2324) {};
        \draw[myarrow, overlay] (n3132) -- +(-1.8,0) node[anchor=east] {$\zeta_y=n_{31}+in_{32}$};
        \draw[myarrow, overlay] (n4142) -- +(-1.8,0) node[anchor=east] {$\tilde{\zeta}_y=n_{41}-in_{42}$};
        \draw[myarrow, overlay] (n1314) -- +(1.8,0) node[anchor=west] {$\zeta_y=n_{13}-in_{14}$};
        \draw[myarrow, overlay] (n2324) -- +(1.8,0) node[anchor=west] {$\tilde{\zeta}_y=n_{23}-in_{24}$};
    \end{tikzpicture}        
\end{align}
\end{strip}

\blindtext[7] % <--- for testing purpose only
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Off-topic: do not use `eqnarray`, see here for the reasons: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/197/101651